# How to determine if a unramifed prime split or not?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, computational-number-theory, number-fields

Let $K$ be the Number field and $L$  be finite extension where $\mathfrak{p}$ prime of K is unramified. Are there any conditions on $\mathfrak{p}$ so that I can say $\mathfrak{p}$ splits completely in L or otherwise.

I am aware of the following result on the Artin symbol.
Artin symbol $\left(\frac{L/K}{\mathfrak{p}}\right) $  is identity if and only if it $\mathfrak{p}$ splits completely in $L.$

Is there a way to compute the Artin symbol? or if you can refer me to some other method, it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question is not research level. The tool you need is the Dedekind--Kummer theorem and any decent textbook on algebraic number theory (e.g. Stewart+Tall) will cover this.

Comment: The answer depends heavily on how $L$ is expressed. If you have $L$ described in terms of the equation of its generator, you want to look at that equation mod $\mathfrak p$. If you have $L$ described using class field theory, you want to look at $\mathfrak p$ mod something.